# How do I analyse a two-alternative forced choice test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, paired-data, choice-modeling

I have recently as part of my bachelor project at my university conducted a two-alternative forced choice test. I have looked at ways to say something with significance about which images (the test participants were given a set of 4 pairs of images, for each pair they had to choose one). While testing is emphasized in my education, I do not have enough knowledge about analysis of the results I have now.

How do I go about figuring something significant out about the independent variables that I am manipulating (in separate scenarios)?

Is logistic regression something I could use or are there methods that are easier to understand for someone who has only had one course of statistics?

**The data (and edits about the data)**:

The data consists of rows of test participants and four columns named as image pairs that the participants were choosing between. The values are the test participants' choice (between the two images in the pair)

I have four independent variables, three of them scales and one nominal that I am changing in four scenarios respectively. Each scenario has *paths* that are chosen "at random" (depending on the last number on the test participant's digital watch e.g. if the time is 13:37, the test participant takes path 7). The reason for the paths is a detail of the implementation in Google Forms to allow all image pair combinations to be presented but not all to every test participant. I would like to find a model for achieving either high probability of one outcome of the dependent binary variable.

- IV: Amount, Spread, Diff objects, Placement model (nominal)
- DV: Image chosen or not.

e.i. if I want a high probability of YES/1/ACCEPT/etc answers (to the binary question: "Does the virtual environment seem inhabited to a greater extend than the other image in this pair of images?"). to an image, what need the ratios between the independent variables be?

Here is a link a copy of the spreadsheet containing the data.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am7BMwlOEiUNdGJhNU1uQlg5QUtxYW1ZNHhfUHlqS1E&usp=sharing

Comment: You don't conduct statistical inference by collecting data and then saying "I wonder what might be statistically significant?". You start with *questions you want to answer*, collect data that well let you answer those particular questions, and then see what it says about those questions. If you collect a bunch of data and then start looking for something significant ... what you're doing sounds awfully like significance-hunting. Instead: *What are some interesting questions you want to ask?* ... or even more basically "*Why would anyone conduct such an experiment?*"

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what data (what variables of what kinds) you have collected? (Also, since it's for your university study, could you please add the `self-study` tag?)

Comment: I have added a short description of the data (will post a link to a copy in a minute too) I did not know of the self-study tag but I have added it on your suggestion, Glen_b.

I see the problem you are raising and I agree that I could be one, there are some variables independent variables I want to see if have an significant effect and this is  how the hypotheses are made up.
I will try to be more consistent from test design to analysis as I am learning.

Comment: I am not sure we should treat this as a self-study question. A student carrying out his or her final bachelor's project is pretty much in the same situation as a researcher facing a reviewer, writing a grant application or completing a dissertation. It's obviously not a well-defined question straight out of a textbook.

Comment: @MHA What you are trying to achieve is still unclear. What are those independent variables (what type/how many)? What question did you ask about those pictures (e.g. were participants supposed to rank them or express preferences)? Did everyone see the same pairs of pictures? Was each picture shown only once or several times? And finally and most importantly: What do you want to learn about those pictures or those scenarios?

Comment: I have four independent variables, three of them scales and one nominal that I am changing in four scenarios respectively. 
I would like to find a model for achieving either high probability of one outcome of the dependent binary variable.

IV: Amount, Spread, Diff objects, Placement model (nominal)
DV: Image chosen or not.

e.i. if I want a high probability of YES/1/ACCEPT/etc answers (to the binary question: "Does the virtual environment seem inhabited to a greater extend than the other image in this pair of images?"). to an image, what need the ratios between the independent variables be?

Comment: @GaëlLaurans The questions seem to be way before the 'facing a reviewer' point, since presumably one doesn't submit a paper before even considering what questions it will answer; the actual questions seem relatively basic to me, and I think given it's for credit, it would be worth signalling 'don't just do the OP's project' as some might otherwise end up doing. I'm content for the tag to be removed if consensus runs the other way.

Comment: @MHA that information about the variables belongs in your question

Comment: @Glen_b What I am trying to say is that, unlike someone working through a textbook or following a course, the OP's goal is addressing some substantive question, not learning statistics. Just as a PhD thesis or typical research study, doing the project means defining a problem, actually collecting data, etc. The main difference is that bachelor students have less experience going in, more modest goals and receive course credit instead of professional reputation and a salary. But there is no “solution”  in the way a textbook problem would.

Comment: @MHA I am still confused. What is a path? How do the scenarios relate to your independent variables? Why do none of your IV show up in the data sample you linked to? Also, what about my previous questions regarding the pictures? In any case, you should follow Glen_b's advice and edit the question to add the details you gave us in the comments.

Comment: The paths were a project group member of mine's way to offer smaller tests in Google Forms while still getting results for all combinations of images (all image pairs).
The result of which is that people only have to spend five minutes each going through fewer images.
Which path (set of image pairs) you are given is chosen based on the last digit of a digital watch at the time the test participant begins the test. (13:37 would give you path 7)
It's not perfect but the number of answers is almost the same for each image pair combination.

Comment: @GaëlLaurans I accept your argument. MHA - if you would like, you should feel free to remove the self-study tag.

Comment: Seeing as I am new to this site, I will take your discussed suggestion and remove it again.

Comment: @MHA I am beginning to understand what you did. I think the experimental design is much more complex that you realized or that the question title suggests. I am not sure I will be able to help but in any case some important details are still missing.

Comment: How do the independent variables enter into the design? You still did not answer that question and they do not appear in your data sample. Did you create the pictures to reflect various levels of “amount”, “spread”, “diff objects” and a “placement model” (whatever that is)? Did you somehow measure these variables for each of your pictures?

Comment: I created the pictures to reflect various amounts of "amount", "spread", "diff objects" and a "placement model", yes.

Correct also that experimental design is more complex than I realized. I'm in a real pickle now.

Comment: My guess is the asker wants to know how to construct a function from the independent variables that, when applied pairwise to <chosen, not-chosen> pairs, is optimal at giving the "chosen" item a higher score.